# How to delay between screenshots?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot, delay, pyautogui

I've been trying to screenshot data from a program so I could then convert it to text because I wanted to automate the whole process. But from some reason, four separate screenshots are taken at the same time although I set `time.sleep()` in multiple places — but when I do the same thing, but with no running the program (just desktop is visible) the screenshots are taken separately.
How can I delay screenshots while inside program?

This is the full code (sorry for code's messiness):

```
import os
import pyautogui as pag
import time
#import pyscreenshot as pscr
from PIL import ImageGrab as scr
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import subprocess

try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

def ocr_core(filename):
    """
    This function will handle the core OCR processing of images.
    """
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    # We'll use Pillow's Image class to open the image and pytesseract to
    # detect the string in the image.
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
    return text

os.startfile('C:\Program Files\Stellarium\stellarium.exe')

time.sleep(8)

pag.hotkey('f3')
pag.typewrite('Delta Cep')
pag.hotkey('enter')

time.sleep(4)
now_cep=datetime.now()
vrijeme_cep=now_cep.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S')
folder='images/'
filename=' Delta Cep.png'
output_cep=folder+vrijeme_cep+filename
time.sleep(2)
im=scr.grab(bbox=(0,0,1919,1079))
im.save(output_cep)
#im=pag.screenshot(region=(0,0,1919,1079))
#im=scr.grab(bbox=(0,0,1919,1079))
#im=scr.grab(bbox=(7,274,330,290))
#im.save(output_cep)
#im.show()

pag.hotkey('f3')
pag.typewrite('Polaris')
pag.hotkey('enter')
time.sleep(4)
now_pol=datetime.now()
vrijeme_pol=now_pol.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S')
folder='images/'
filename=' Polaris.png'
output_pol=folder+vrijeme_pol+filename
time.sleep(2)
im1=scr.grab(bbox=(0,0,1919,1079))
#im=scr.grab(bbox=(8,299,326,314))
im1.save(output_pol)
#im.show()

pag.hotkey('f3')
pag.typewrite('X Cyg')
pag.hotkey('enter')
time.sleep(4)
now_x=datetime.now()
vrijeme_x=now_x.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S')
folder='images/'
filename=' X Cyg.png'
output_x=folder+vrijeme_x+filename
time.sleep(2)
im2=scr.grab(bbox=(0,0,1919,1079))
#im=scr.grab(bbox=(7,290,328,305))
im2.save(output_x)
#im.show()

pag.hotkey('f3')
pag.typewrite('SU Cyg')
pag.hotkey('enter')
time.sleep(4)
now_su=datetime.now()
vrijeme_su=now_su.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S')
folder='images/'
filename=' SU Cyg.png'
output_su=folder+vrijeme_su+filename
im3=scr.grab(bbox=(0,0,1919,1079))
#im=scr.grab(bbox=(6,289,327,305))
im3.save(output_su)
#im.show()

x=ocr_core(output_cep)
x=x.split('\n',1)
x=x[0]
x=x.replace('Next maximum light: ','')
x=x.replace(' UTC','')
print(x)
x=x.replace('2020-08-','')
x=x.replace(x[x.find(' '):len(x)],'')
x=date(2020,8,int(x)).toordinal()+1721425
print(x)

y=ocr_core(output_pol)
y=y.split('\n',1)
y=y[0]
y=y.replace('Next maximum light: ','')
y=y.replace(' UTC','')
y=date(2020,8,int(y)).toordinal()+1721425

z=ocr_core(output_cep)
z=z.split('\n',1)
z=z[0]
z=z.replace('Next maximum light: ','')
z=z.replace(' UTC','')
z=date(2020,8,int(z)).toordinal()+1721425

q=ocr_core(output_cep)
q=q.split('\n',1)
q=q[0]
q=q.replace('Next maximum light: ','')
q=q.replace(' UTC','')
q=date(2020,8,int(q)).toordinal()+1721425



print(x+'\n'+y+'\n'+z+'\n'+q)

os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM stellarium.exe')

subprocess.Popen('explorer "D:\Dokumenti\INFORMATIKA\images"')
```

Here is the screenshot inside the program and all of the screenshots i got were the same (time at the bottom of the screen was identical).
[screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDpVN.jpg)

But on desktop you can see that screenshots were taken at different times.
[desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbFUX.png)
[desktop screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4ZSl.png)

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Code took screenshots as soon as program loaded because it was in fullscreen mode. Solution is to run the program in windowed mode.